# Why my toolbar not setting menu on fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am building  android shopping app that have the cart menu item and all products are opening in fragment and i want to set the MainActivity menu items on the product fragment and other fragments.

So the user is easy to open the cart from the product view fragment.below code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_view_fragment, null);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    this.context = getContext();
    String id=getArguments().getString("message");
    //String size=getArguments().getString("size");
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager(getContext());
     email = sessionManager.getUserDetails().get("id");
    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    GetOneProduct(id);
    return view;
}
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:segmentedgroup="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@android:style/Animation.Activity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/Black" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


Blockquote
```

Comment: yes i want same menu in the toolbar @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use a single activity approach.
Then your activity should include Toolbar in its layout something like this.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".navigation.HomeActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/app_navigation" />
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView> 
   // if you have bottom nav.
   </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
```

Then set up the toolbar as you wish in your activity.

Comment: my mainActivity have alrady ActionBar so the menu items are showing on that but i ant that also show on the my product fragment that have toolbar

Comment: @grubbasketfood Do you have any reason to keep another toolbar in the fragment?

Comment: yes I want to show cart menu on toolbar that showing all product count

Comment: @grubbasketfood Okay, unless I misunderstood or you want to have 2 toolbars in your app. 
Remove the toolbar from fragment layout and place into the activity layout only like the code snippet. This way regardless of fragment transaction the activity toolbar stay as it is.